# ConnectionError: exception while running queryset on elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using django-elasticsearch in my django application 
,here is the link to follow the steps 
https://github.com/liberation/django-elasticsearch

Before configuration with my django app I need to first test elasticsearch in shell as per mentioned in above link.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_elasticsearch.models import EsIndexable

class Product(EsIndexable, models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
```

After this as per mentioned in steps I did this in python shell

```
>>> q = Product.es.search('sample')
>>> q
```

and I got this error in shell

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x10828e250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
61] Connection refused) caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x10828e250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] 
Connection refused)
```

How do I proceed now, so that I should get result as

```
[{'id': 1, 'product_name': 'sample'}, {'id': 2, 'product_name': 'samp'}, ...]
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Also please suggest some good documentation and step by step workflow to achieve this functionality in my django app to search the products based on their names.

Comment: Is elasticsearch is running in `9200` ?

Comment: I dont know how to do it or how to check it. Can you please elaborate the process. I have tried lot of stuffs but its not working.

Comment: @sunny-chaudhari Please check `http://you-server.url:9200` in browser